# Why is my SQL returning 0 rows when comparing the current time to a timestamp column?

Tags: mysql

I want to determine if a user has an active subscription.  So the activation_date column must be less than the current time and the expiration_date column must be greater than the current time.  The query always returns 0 results.  Why is this?  Here is my MySQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    `s`.`subscription_id`, `s`.`plan_id`, `s`.`member_id`, `s`.`activation_date`, `s`.`expiration_date`, `s`.`period` as cycle, `s`.`amount`, 
    `p`.`plan_id`, `p`.`title` as plan_title 
FROM (`subscriptions` as s)
LEFT JOIN `plans` as p ON `s`.`plan_id` = `p`.`plan_id` 
WHERE `s`.`member_id` = '1' 
    AND `s`.`activation_date` <= 'NOW()' 
    AND `s`.`expiration_date` >= 'NOW()' 
LIMIT 1
```

Here are the table results:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not comparing the columns to the current timestamp (i.e. the return value of `NOW()`) but to the actual string `'NOW()'`. In order to use the result of the function, you have to get rid of the quotes.

Comment: Arrgg... god damned codeigniter compiles the quotes automatically.  i figured it was something stupid like that.